# What type of file is an .mpkx and how can I open it?

Tags: file-formats

I have not opened an mpkx file.  Is this a 2D or 3D file.  I am guessing that it is a compressed ArcGIS file of some type.  It does not show up as an option in ArcGIS or QGIS.

Can someone suggest how to open this?

Comment: Possibly an Esri map package file ~ https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/sharing/overview/map-package.htm

Comment: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/arcgis-pro-won-t-recognize-an-mpkx-file/td-p/80119

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.mpkx are ArcGIS Pro Map packages files.
If you have ArcGIS Pro then the instructions on how to [Import an ArcGIS Pro map package](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/projects/add-maps-to-a-project.htm#GUID-B5D6CDC1-A150-4FEF-833F-F6AAC0D92890) are available in the help file.

If you are using QGIS, then you can unpack the file with 7zip and at least get the data. However QGIS can't directly read the maps and layouts.