# How to extract layers from a mpkx file?

Tags: gdal, ogr, usgs, mpkx

I would like to use the [World Terrestrial Ecosystems](https://rmgsc.cr.usgs.gov/outgoing/ecosystems/Global) data published by the USGS. It is made available in the form of a compressed file in the [mpkx format](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/430404/what-type-of-file-is-an-mpkx-and-how-can-i-open-it). I expect this file to contain one or more global rasters.

[GDAL/OGR](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html) announces capabilities to abstract this file format, however, it is not functioning with this particular file.

```bash
$ gdalinfo USGSEsriTNCWorldTerrestrialEcosystems2020.mpkx
ERROR 4: `USGSEsriTNCWorldTerrestrialEcosystems2020.mpkx' not recognized as a supported file format.
gdalinfo failed - unable to open 'USGSEsriTNCWorldTerrestrialEcosystems2020.mpkx'.

$ ogrinfo USGSEsriTNCWorldTerrestrialEcosystems2020.mpkx
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `USGSEsriTNCWorldTerrestrialEcosystems2020.mpkx' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRIC
  -> FITS
  -> PCIDSK
  -> netCDF
  -> PDS4
[...]
```

I thus uncompressed the file with the 7zip utility, resulting in many tens of files with the `.bundle` extension. There are also a few files with a `.gdb*` extension, alluding at the Geo-database format. GDAL is also capable of abstracting this format, however in this bundle there is no file with the extact `.gdb` extension, just a `gdb` file, that GDAL cannot interpret.

```bash
$ ls -la *gdb*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   110 okt 29  2021 a00000001.gdbindexes
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   339 dec 15  2022 a00000001.gdbtable
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  5152 dec 15  2022 a00000001.gdbtablx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  2055 okt 29  2021 a00000002.gdbtable
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  5152 okt 29  2021 a00000002.gdbtablx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    42 okt 29  2021 a00000003.gdbindexes
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   525 okt 29  2021 a00000003.gdbtable
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  5152 okt 29  2021 a00000003.gdbtablx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   310 okt 29  2021 a00000004.gdbindexes
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 15671 dec 15  2022 a00000004.gdbtable
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  5152 dec 15  2022 a00000004.gdbtablx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   296 okt 29  2021 a00000005.gdbindexes
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  2071 okt 29  2021 a00000005.gdbtable
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  5152 okt 29  2021 a00000005.gdbtablx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   318 okt 29  2021 a00000006.gdbindexes
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   263 dec 15  2022 a00000006.gdbtable
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  5152 dec 15  2022 a00000006.gdbtablx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   602 okt 29  2021 a00000007.gdbindexes
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  3626 okt 29  2021 a00000007.gdbtable
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  5152 okt 29  2021 a00000007.gdbtablx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    66 dec 15  2022 a00000009.gdbindexes
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 54235 dec 15  2022 a00000009.gdbtable
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  5152 dec 15  2022 a00000009.gdbtablx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user     4 okt 29  2021 gdb

$ gdalinfo gdb
ERROR 4: `gdb' not recognized as a supported file format.
gdalinfo failed - unable to open 'gdb'.

$ ogrinfo gdb
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `gdb' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRIC
  -> FITS
  -> PCIDSK
[...]
```

Is there any way to extract whatever layers may be bundled in this file?

Comment: Try gdalinfo one level up, for the directory that contains all those files.

Comment: @user30184 This kind of works, but with `ogrinfo` directed at the folder with uncompressed files. However, `ogrinfo` only reports an attribute table, not the geometries themselves. `ogr2ogr` is able to retrieve that attribute table, but no geometries. Out of 360 MB in the original file, `ogr2ogr` retrieves 140 KB.

Comment: Is that vector or raster filegdb?

Comment: I downloaded the data. Unfortunately I have no idea about how to open that data with GDAL. I used GDAL 3.9dev for testing, both directly from the map package and from un-7zipped directories, always with no success. Write mail to gdal-dev mailing list and ask if someone could help you.